# Node js and Code First

Tags: node.js, database, code-first

I've worked on Entity Framework with Code First approach. Now I am learning Node.js I wonder is there a way to make the same code first approach using Node.js and some libraly? I am thinking of using MySql as database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can look into [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/). Example of usage from the home page (I added comments to relate to Code First):

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
// define your "context"
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

// define your "entities"
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  birthday: Sequelize.DATE
});

// use them
sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  return User.create({
    username: 'janedoe',
    birthday: new Date(1980, 6, 20)
  });
}).then(function(jane) {
  console.log(jane.get({
    plain: true
  }));
});
```

Comment: I think this is what I am searching for. Can you open migrations with it? Or you should combine it with the mysql libraly?

Comment: I don't use Sequelize but there is a support for migrations: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/