# How do I do control flow in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make my sql database version controlled and to have the series of scripts completely re-runnable such that no matter what the database version is (held in a table called database_version) the scripts will run the appropriate sql files

here is my where I am at

I have a master.sql where I just write this kind of thing

```
source 001-createdb.sql
source 002-addusertable.sql
source 003-seed-data.sql
```

and then a file where the version in the version table is tested against the version of the changes

```
SET @expectedVersion = "1.0.0";

SELECT Version, Id
INTO @currentVersion, @currentVersionId
FROM database_version
ORDER BY Id DESC
LIMIT 1;


-- THIS WHERE I'M STUCK

IF @currentVersion = @expectedVersion THEN

-- DO all the things
-- i.e. create table, update table, migrate data, whatever

END
```

```

If it can't be done I'll just switch to postgres

Comment: After doing some research I think the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010741/node-js-and-code-first

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow using control flow statements in scripts. I could suggest you to split script into some different parts (sql-files), and execute them one-by-one if needed.